# How to exclude weekends while opening file in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, date

everyday one file will create with date as previous working day.
Example, (05/16/2017, Tuesday) file will create with date as 05/15/2017, Monday.
whereas on 05/15/2017, Monday file will create with date as 05/12/2017.

I am trying to open file using VBA with the below code,
file name Format=`"C:\users\Duke\report'05/15/2017'.XLS"`

```
sub OpenFile()    
  Const fpath As String = "C:\users\Duke\Report"  
  Dim fname As String

fname = Format(Date - (Weekday((Date),Vbmonday) - 1), "yyyy-mm-dd")  
fname = "'" & fname & "'" & ".XLS"

  Dim path As String
path = fpath & fname

end ()
```

But it is not working, Please suggest.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Syntax wise, the last line should be `End Sub` and not `end OpenFile()`  There is also no line in which you execute a statement that might open the file.

Comment: if this code ran on monday, fname will return 0 so the desired file, meaning file with fridays date is not opening.

Comment: Also you need to add "/" to the end of your path, because now you are calling file "C:\users\Duke\Reportreport'05/15/2017'.XLS". You should use debug.print your variables in run time to see what actually the code is calling.

Answer (score 0):

VBA does not have a built in method to handle workdays.  But the following might compute the desired date, if your code only runs M-F and SS are weekends:

```
  Dim X As Long
  X = IIf(Weekday(Date) = vbMonday, 3, 1)
fname = Format(Date - X, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

If your code might also run on the weekends, then you will have to define what you want to happen, in that event